# How to split an arranger clip based on pitch in Bitwig 8-Track

Tags: midi, daw, arranging, bitwig

I have recorded a MIDI "Arranger Clip" in the Bitwig 8-Track DAW software.  I do this often and just jam on the instrument.

Afterwards, sometimes I find that I would like to separate the clip into separate bass and treble tracks, so that I can create patches or re-record some specific sections more easily.

I can do this already by duplicating the clip and manually deleting the notes that I don't want from each copy.  But I'd like to find an easier way, for example to specify a pitch value and have the track split automatically.  All the other posts on splitting seem to be more about splitting based on time or modifying tempo, rather than splitting based on pitch.

Is there a way to do this with either pre- or post-production configuration or editing tools using Bitwig 8-Track?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the split procedure for better organization, but if you want a live performance setup or a simple jamming bwpreset that you use with both a bass and chord sound, you can use an instrument layer with Note Filter devices.
Simply make two layers, put a note filter on each, set the bounds, and put your instruments on these layers after the filters. For quicker adjustment of the split pitch, you can use a macro modulator on the instrument layer (but only with BW2)
If you don't care about workflow, using this note filter trick, you can basically use just 1 or 2 track for all your Bitwig projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this done with the MultibandFX-2 device that Bitwig comes with.  The way I see that you can do this is to disable the output (set to no output) on the track you're wanting to separate, and make two tracks with an Audio Receiver device and the MultibandFX-2.  Set the Audio Receiver's source to your track on both, then drop to zero the high knob on one to make the bass track and drop the low knob on the other track for treble.  You'll want the mix setting turned up 100% on all these.  You can also adjust the split frequency.  Hope this helps.  I have found Bitwig to be the easiest DAW to understand and figure out, hope you have found it useful!

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting using audio filtering? If what he has is MIDI then filtering the MIDI notes like user3093578 suggested seems like it would be a much better solution, as it will separate them entirely where filtering the audio will still leave some amount of sound bleeding between the two...